# Python Dictionary with generic keys and Callable[T] values

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, mypy

I have some named tuples:

```
JOIN = NamedTuple("JOIN", [])
EXIT = NamedTuple("EXIT", [])
```

I also have functions to handle each type of tuple with:

```
def handleJoin(t: JOIN) -> bool:
    pass

def handleExit(t: EXIT) -> bool:
    pass
```

What I want to do is create a dictionary `handleTuple` so I can call it like so:

```
t: Union[JOIN, EXIT] = #an instance of JOIN or EXIT
result: bool
result = handleTuple[type(t)](t)
```

What I cannot figure out is how to define said dictionary. I tried defining a generic `T`:

```
T = TypeVar("T", JOIN, EXIT)
handleTuple: Dict[T, Callable[[T], bool]
```

However I get an error saying "Type variable T is unbound" which I do not understand. The closest I have got so far is:

```
handleTuple: Dict[Type[Union[JOIN, EXIT]], bool]
handleTuple = {
    JOIN: True
    EXIT: False
}
```

This works fine for calling it the way I want, however I cannot figure out the `Callable` part in the definition so I can include my functions. How can I do this

Comment: FWIW, this might be suitable for a ``functools.singledispatch`` ("overloaded") function instead of a ``dict``. This should automatically provide the proper static typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeVars are only meaningful in aliases, classes and functions. One can define a [`Protocol` for the lookup](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol):

```py
T = TypeVar("T", JOIN, EXIT, contravariant=True)

class Handler(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, item: Type[T]) -> Callable[[T], bool]:
        ...

handleTuple = cast(Handler, {JOIN: handleJoin, EXIT: handleExit})
```

The special method `self.__getitem__(item)` corresponds to `self[item]`. Thus, the protocol defines that accessing `handleTuple[item]` with `item: Type[T]` evaluates to some `Callable[[T], bool]`. The `cast` is currently needed for type checkers such as MyPy to understand that the `dict` is a valid implementation of this protocol.

---

Since the code effectively implements a single dispatch, defining a [`functools.singledispatch` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) provides the behaviour out of the box:

```py
@singledispatch
def handle(t) -> bool:
    raise NotImplementedError

@handle.register
def handleJoin(t: JOIN) -> bool:
    pass

@handle.register
def handleExit(t: EXIT) -> bool:
    pass

t: Union[JOIN, EXIT]
result: bool
result = handle(t)
```

Comment: Works great, I had to use [`singledispatchmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) because my functions are in a class, but I did not include this in the question body. Thanks for leading me to it!

Comment: Can you please explain the Protocol method though? Specifically, what goes in `__getitem__`? The documentation is pretty sparse

Comment: @stybl I've added some explanation on how ``__getitem__`` works here. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi mypy 0.790 reports this error: `Missing type parameters for generic type "Handler"  [type-arg]` for the line defining `handleTuple`

Comment: The error message requires passing --strict to mypy

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The `__getitem__` example doesn't work, because you have to specify `T` when you declare `handleTuple` like `handleTuple: Handler[JOIN] = {JOIN: handleJoin, EXIT: handleExit}` but then that doesn't make sense any more.

Comment: @EllisPercival Thanks for the heads up – there was something else wrong with it as well. I've fixed both, but it requires a ``cast`` to make MyPy accept the dict. :/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy update! I'd all but given up, so I'll see if this fits into my design.

Comment: This answer served as boilerplate for a similar problem I was having, though what if the handler item type isn't the same as the callback parameter type? I asked a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742346/how-to-define-pairs-or-tuples-of-acceptable-types-to-generic-protocol) about how to constrain the protocol in this case.