# How can I use type hinting in Python for dictionaries with tuples (data type, callable that returns object of this data type)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

This is my first question, so I hope I don't miss any important field.

I'm new to python type-hinting, and I'm not sure how to provide a type hint for a dictionary that I used for a project.

The dictionary has **strings** as keys. The values are **tuples** with two elements: a data type and a callable for obtaining an object of the same data type as the first element of the tuple. For each key, the data type can be any, but its corresponding callable must return an object of this data type.

In other words, the dictionary is somehow a map that enables you to subtract fields from an object using the callable. It also tells you the expected data type of the object that you subtracted (this may be useful if you want to dynamically create a table in a database to store all the fields of an object). I have a dummy example below:

```
class VeryComplexClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.string_ivar = "internal variable"
        self.bool_ivar = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "string representation"

    def __bool__(self):
        return False



object = VeryComplexClass()

my_dict = {  # This is the dictionary I want to provide type hinting to
    "i_string": (str, lambda x: x.string_ivar),
    "i_bool": (bool, lambda x: x.bool_ivar),
    "o_string": (str, lambda x: str(x),
    "o_bool": (bool, lambda x: bool(x),
    "object": (VeryComplexClass, lambda x: x),
}

my_dict["i_string"][1](object)  # It returns "internal variable"
my_dict["i_bool"][1](object)  # It returns True
my_dict["o_string"][1](object)  # It returns "string representation"
my_dict["o_bool"][1](object)  # It returns False
my_dict["object"][1](object)  # It returns the object itself
```

So far, I have the following:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Tuple, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

my_dict: Dict[str, Tuple[Type[T], Callable[[Any], T]] = {
    "i_string": (str, lambda x: x.string_ivar),
    "i_bool": (bool, lambda x: x.bool_ivar),
    "o_string": (str, lambda x: str(x),
    "o_bool": (bool, lambda x: bool(x),
}
```

However, I'm not 100% sure this is what I want:

- Does this notation accept different data types for each value of the dictionary?
- Does this notation clearly state that the callable of the tuple must return an object with the same data type as the first element of the tuple?
- With this notation, can I insert/pop items in the dictionary? (users may want to add new fields to be subtracted from the arbitrary object).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Dictionary with generic keys and Callable T values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65107269/python-dictionary-with-generic-keys-and-callablet-values)

Comment: "However, I'm not 100% sure this is what I want." Can you clarify what you want? Does the dictionary always consist of a fixed set of key,values or do you add/remove entries? Is the dictionary large or even generated automatically?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I edited the question so it is clearer now what I want.