# How to define pairs or tuples of acceptable types to generic protocol

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy

Below is a rough example of building a dispatch interface for handling, e.g., messages coming in over the network. Each message contains a header with a MessageIdentifier, and the application is able to define various callbacks for the corresponding parsed ConcreteMessage types.

The crux of the dispatch is defining the associations between MessageIdentifiers and ConcreteMessages, defined in `handle_message` below. At runtime, this is type-safe because it's not possible for a callback to be called with anything other than its appropriate type. But I'm wondering if it's possible to constrain the allowed pairs of identifiers and concrete messages for mypy, ideally to show an error when a callback is called with the incorrect type.

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar, cast
from typing_extensions import Literal, Protocol

class MessageType(Enum):
    FOO = 0
    BAR = 1
    BAZ = 2

class FooMessage: ...
class BarMessage: ...
class BazMessage: ...

ConcreteMessage = TypeVar("ConcreteMessage", FooMessage, BarMessage, BazMessage)
MessageIdentifier = TypeVar("MessageIdentifier", Literal[MessageType.FOO], Literal[MessageType.BAR], Literal[MessageType.BAZ])

class MessageHandler(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, item: MessageIdentifier) -> Callable[[ConcreteMessage], Optional[bool]]: ...

def handle_foo(foo: FooMessage) -> Optional[bool]: ...
def handle_bar(bar: BarMessage) -> Optional[bool]: ...

handle_message = cast(MessageHandler, {
    MessageType.FOO: handle_foo,
    MessageType.BAR: handle_bar,
})

# MessageIdentifier constrains correctly
func = handle_message[5]                # error: Value of type variable "MessageIdentifier" of "__getitem__" of "MessageHandler" cannot be "Literal[5]"
func = handle_message[MessageType.FOO]  # good
# ConcreteMessage constrains correctly
func(FooMessage())  # good
func(5)             # error: Value of type variable "ConcreteMessage" of function cannot be "int"
func(BarMessage())  # good - but would ideally be an error
```

Said another way, rather than the `MessageHandler` accepting the *cross-product* of `ConcreteMessage`, `MessageIdentifier` (as if `Tuple[ConcreteMessage, MessageIdentifier]`), can I explicitly define the pairs of types that are acceptable for the `Protocol`?

---

Bonus points if you can also determine why the `cast` to `MessageHandler` is necessary. When defined as follows:

```
handle_message: MessageHandler = {
    MessageType.FOO: handle_foo,
    MessageType.BAR: handle_bar,
}
```

mypy reports `Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Literal[MessageType.FOO]": "Callable[[FooMessage], Optional[bool]]"; expected "MessageIdentifier": "Callable[[ConcreteMessage], Optional[bool]]"`.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.8 and mypy 0.910.

Comment: You can ``@overload`` ``__getitem__`` for each pair of concrete types. There isn't really a point in using ``TypeVar``s when they are used in just one place.

Comment: Thank you, that does work! At the cost of requiring the associations to be maintained in two places, in the protocol and the dictionary implementing the protocol. I suppose my original code had the types in the TypeVar and the dictionary, as well. I think I'm slowly learning that Python type hints are just that - hints - and not template parameters like in C++.